# How can I use page inside of my page.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Inside of this method that works with puppeteer, I want to use `page` but I can't quite work out how to get it inside the Promise.

```
async scrollList( page ) {
    let results = await page.evaluate( async () => {
        results = await new Promise( async resolve => {
            // next line fails :-(
            await page.mouse.move( 100, 100 );

            // do other stuff
            return resolve( results );
        });
    });

    console.log('Got results: ', results);
}
```

How can I do this? Right now I'm getting an error saying `page` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

You cannot access page as the two runtimes (Node.js and browser) are separated. The `page` object can only be accessed from within the Node.js runtime.

**Solution**

You have to expose a function that can access the `page` object to do that via [page.exposeFunction](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction):

```js
await page.exposeFunction('moveMouse', async (x, y) => {
    // page is accessible here
    await page.mouse.move(x, y);
});
```

You can use that function inside `page.evaluate` by calling `window.moveMouse(100, 100)`.