# Fetch/promise functions not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, browser, promise, fetch, heic

Im using 2 libraries (heic2any and image conversion) to try convert and compress heic images to jpeg. At the moment Im having issues to get the promises to return in the correct order

```
e = screenInput(e);

async function screenInput(filename) {
  //checks file extension
  var ext = getExtension(filename);
  switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'png':
    case 'bmp':
      return(compressim(filename));
      break;
    case 'heic':
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(filename)
      var result = await heicConvert(url)
      return compressOnly(result);
      break;
    default:
      return filename
      break;
  }
}


 function heicConvert(input) {
   return fetch(input)
    .then((res)=>res.blob())
    .then((blob)=>(heic2any({blob,toType:"image/jpeg"})))
  }

  function compressOnly(image) {
  var file
  file = new File([imageConversion.compressAccurately(image,500)], image.name, {type: "image/jpeg"})
  return file
}
```

at the moment its returning a pending promise on

```
var result = await heicConvert(url)
```

before even getting to
compressOnly(result);

Any help would be appreciated, been stuck on this for a while!

Comment: Does `heic2any({blob,toType:"image/jpeg"})` return a promise? Maybe try another chain `.then(blob=>heic2any({blob,toType:"image/jpeg"})).then(heic=>heic)`

Comment: Why are you invoking heic2any immediately? Return in instead:
`.then( (blob) => heic2any( { blob,toType:"image/jpeg" } ))`

Comment: @ptothep yes it does return a promise, I've tried other chains but sadly no result

Comment: @SebastianAmmon I don't understand your suggestion. Isn't this what the code already does? It will only call `heic2any` when the promise chain resolves.

Comment: @SebastianAmmon I invoke it immediately as its recommended in the docs, and It returns screenInput before I get a chance to invoke it

Comment: may be this helped you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019621/using-async-await-and-then-together and https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: what is this code for: `e = screenInput(e)`? e will always receive a Promise here...

Comment: @SebastianAmmon just where I call the function, and thats the issue im having, my functions are always preemptively returning

Comment: I removed async from screenInput, so it doesnt return a promise, which makes sense, and added async to heicConvert, but heicConvert is still returning a pending with await on the fetch

Comment: @callumonroute, can you try adding a `catch` statement to your `fetch` chain in `heicConvert` to see if there is any useful error message that might help you resolve the issue?

Comment: @colin I've added it, but no error, I think its just the way im handling the promises, but not sure how to fix it!

Comment: @callumonroute your `screenInput` function looks fine. Remember however that it would return a Promise, so you need to handle it with `screenInput().then(() => ...)` there is no other way around it. If you're working with promises, there will be a point where the top level needs to wait for the promise to resolve.

Comment: @callumonroute, I'm not sure of all the details of your code but it looks to me like you are calling `URL.createObjectURL(filename)`. Is filename a string or a file object. I'm wondering if what you are passing to `heic2any` via `heicConvert` is not what it is expecting. Hence the unresolved promise. From the `heic2any` docs it looks like it calls `URL.createObject` on the blob conversion result?

Comment: @callumonroute - Here's a simplistic codesandbox that mimics what you are doing. It's obviously missing some detail because i don't know where `screenInput` is called from or what is being passed to it. https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-jones-z8b6l?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I cannot believe that the `result` from `var result = await heicConvert(url)` would be a pending promise

Comment: @bergi you are correct the problem is the `heicConvert` is not returning a promise. The code needs re-organised so that `heicConvert` returns a promise and rejects or resolves with the output of `heic2any`

Comment: @callumonroute, i've updated that codesandbox to show how you might change the `heicConvert` function to return a promise https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-jones-z8b6l?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @colin No, in the code that the OP posted in the question, `heicConvert` *does* return a promise just fine. That code is working. `heicConvert(url)` returns a promise, `await heicConvert(url)` evaluates to the promise result. No "pending promise" problem anywhere.

Comment: @colin the code in the sandbox that colin provided works well, thank you so much!

Comment: @callumonroute - np i was beginning to second guess myself there. I knew there was a solution in here somewhere :-)