# S3 getSignedUrl v2 equivalent in AWS Javascript SDK v3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I just started using aws-sdk on my app to upload files to S3, and i'm debating whether to use aws-sdk v2 or v3.

V2 is the whole package, which is super bloated considering i only need the s3 services, not the myriad of other options. However, the documentation is very cryptic and im having a really hard time getting the equivalent getSignedUrl function to work in v3.

In v2, i have this code to sign the url and it works fine. I am using express on the server

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';

const signS3URL = (req,res,next) => {
    const s3 = new aws.S3({region:'us-east-2'});
    const {fileName,fileType} = req.query;
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket : process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key : fileName,
        ContentType:fileType,
        Expires: 60,
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject',s3Params,(err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            next(err);
        }
        res.json(data);
    });
}
```

Now I've been reading documentation and examples trying to get the v3 equivalent to work, but i cant find any working example of how to use it. Here is how I have set it up so far

```
import {S3Client,PutObjectCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import {getSignedUrl} from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';

export const signS3URL = async(req,res,next) => {
    console.log('Sign')
    const {fileName,fileType} = req.query;
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket : process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key : fileName,
        ContentType:fileType,
        Expires: 60,
        // ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    const s3 = new S3Client()
    s3.config.region = 'us-east-2'
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(s3Params)
    console.log(command)


    await getSignedUrl(s3,command).then(signature =>{
        console.log(signature)
        res.json(signature)
    }).catch(e=>next(e))
}
```

There are some errors in this code, and the first I can identify is creating the `command` variable using the `PutObjectCommand` function provided by the SDK. The documentation does not clarify to me what i need to pass it as the "input" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/putobjectcommandinput.html

Does anyone with experience using aws-sdk v3 know how to do this?

Also a side-question, where can i find the api reference for v2???? cuz all i find is the sdk docs that say "v3 now available" and i cant seem to find the reference to v2....

thanks for your time

Comment: I would not use both await and then. Did you try `const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command);`? Version 2 docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/_index.html).

Comment: why woulndt you. use await and then? in the end it's just handling the promise right? I can try `const url = await getSignedUrl...` and will let u know, but i think the issue im having is with the PutObjectCommand params

Comment: Actually it looks as if the `PutObjectCommand` is working ok, i think... i tried changing the await function to how you described it, but im getting the same error. The error is `TypeError: date.getUTCFullYear is not a function`  so i must be passing a wrong parameter somewhere

Comment: See [using await and then together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019621/using-async-await-and-then-together). In my opinion, it's unnecessary, it's less clear, and it can lead to confusion about which code is doing what.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code would give you a signedUrl in a JSON body with the key as `signedUrl`.

```
const signS3URL = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { fileName, fileType } = req.query;
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: fileName,
        ContentType: fileType,
        // ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'
    };
    const s3 = new S3Client({ region: 'us-east-2' })
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(s3Params);

    try {
        const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 60 });
        console.log(signedUrl);
        res.json({ signedUrl })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        next(err);
    }
}
```

Keep the `ACL` as `bucket-owner-full-control` if you want the AWS account owning the Bucket to access the files.

You can go to the `API Reference` for both the JS SDK versions from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/index.html)

Comment: getSignedUrl is undefined, please update your answer with a valid import

Comment: The imports are part of the question. This only answers the function code to get the relevant URL. Not sure no one pointed out the other missing imports for S3Client, PutObjectCommand. 

The required import
`import {getSignedUrl} from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';`

Answer (score 3):

In reference to the AWS docs and @GSSwain's answer (cannot comment, new) this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html) will show multiple examples  `getSignedURL` examples.

Below is an example of uploading copied from AWS docs

```
// Import the required AWS SDK clients and commands for Node.js

import {
  CreateBucketCommand,
  DeleteObjectCommand,
  PutObjectCommand,
  DeleteBucketCommand }
from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { s3Client } from "./libs/s3Client.js"; // Helper function that creates an Amazon S3 service client module.
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

// Set parameters
// Create a random name for the Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket and key
export const bucketParams = {
  Bucket: `test-bucket-${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ** 10)}`,
  Key: `test-object-${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ** 10)}`,
  Body: "BODY"
};
export const run = async () => {
  try {
    // Create an S3 bucket.
    console.log(`Creating bucket ${bucketParams.Bucket}`);
    await s3Client.send(new CreateBucketCommand({ Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket }));
    console.log(`Waiting for "${bucketParams.Bucket}" bucket creation...`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error creating bucket", err);
  }
  try {
    // Create a command to put the object in the S3 bucket.
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(bucketParams);
    // Create the presigned URL.
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
      expiresIn: 3600,
    });
    console.log(
      `\nPutting "${bucketParams.Key}" using signedUrl with body "${bucketParams.Body}" in v3`
    );
    console.log(signedUrl);
    const response = await fetch(signedUrl, {method: 'PUT', body: bucketParams.Body});
    console.log(
      `\nResponse returned by signed URL: ${await response.text()}\n`
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error creating presigned URL", err);
  }

  try {
    // Delete the object.
    console.log(`\nDeleting object "${bucketParams.Key}"} from bucket`);
    await s3Client.send(
      new DeleteObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket, Key: bucketParams.Key })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error deleting object", err);
  }
  try {
    // Delete the S3 bucket.
    console.log(`\nDeleting bucket ${bucketParams.Bucket}`);
    await s3Client.send(
      new DeleteBucketCommand({ Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error deleting bucket", err);
  }
};
run();
```