# JavaScript : How to wait for camera access before proceed execution?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have the following code from Twilio to access local camera on browser :

```
async function ShowLocalVideo() {   
    Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack().then(track => {
        const localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('LocalMedia');
        localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());        
      });
}
```

I would like to make sure the user Granted Access to the camera before continuing the execution of other steps. Or at least he responded. So I'm calling

```
await ShowLocalVideo();
alert('Hi !');
```

But alert **Hi !** is trigerred before the browser says : This file wants to use your camera.

Is is possible to make sure the code doesn't continue until the user responds to **This file wants to use your camera.** ?

Thanks,
Cheers

Comment: You're awaiting ShowLocalVideo but there's another async call within that (the "then" callback) which you're not waiting for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019621/using-async-await-and-then-together (and many others)

Comment: where this code is executed `await ShowLocalVideo();`?

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing `async`/`await` syntax with using Promise `.then`.
Since you're not `await`ing on the result of `createLocalVideoTrack().then(...)`, the async function will return early. You can correct this by replacing `.then` with `await` the following way:

```js
async function ShowLocalVideo() {   
    const track = await Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack();
    const localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('LocalMedia');
    localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());        
}
```

Alternatively, you can await on the result of `createLocalVideoTrack().then(...)`, but that would mix the styles and create confusion.