# Why is the response from my api not being returned to my unit test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, async-await

I strongly suspect this is to do with the api using an asynchronous call, but so far as I can see, I have 'awaits' in all the right places.

The unit test making the call:

```
const { expect } = require('@jest/globals');
const { getWorkerId } = require('../api');

describe("Workers api", () => {
    test("it should return a status of 200", async () => {
        let response = await getWorkerId(21882000)
        expect(response.status).to.equal('200')
    });
});
```

and the api itself:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getWorkerId = async (id) => {
    await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/v1/workers/${id}`)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.status);
            return response;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error number: ', error.errno);
            console.log('Error code: ', error.code);
            return error;
        })
};

module.exports = { getWorkerId };
```

The line 'console.log(response.status)' outputs '200' as expected and if I change the code to display 'response', sure enough there it is. Yet, my unit test's expect call comes back with: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined'.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common to get confused with async/await and Promises in JS. I will try to be concise here, but it is a large topic, with a lot of details, so bear with me on this one!

First and foremost, when using async/await, there is no need to use `.then()`. The `await` keyword will (quite literally) await for the Promise to be resolved, and get its returned value. Similarly, the `.then()` will get the resolved value of the promise, which is the parameter you receive, in your case, it is the `response` inside the `.then()`.

So, the `await`, and the `.then()` work in similar ways, and you can even use them together, like this:

```
const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
  return data
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
  return err
})

console.log(response.status) // Output is 200
```

What is happening above, is that the `await` gets the return of `.then()`, and assigns it to `response`. So, if you use async/await together with `.then()`, you should have a variable to receive the value returned by the `.then()`, so that you can use it outside of the scope.

However, in your case, we have the following:

```
const getJsonPlaceholder = async (id) => {
  await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    return data
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    return err
  })
}

const response2 = await getJsonPlaceholder()

console.log(response2.status)// Output is "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"
```

What is happening is that the `await` receives the returned value by `.then()`, assigns it to nothing at all, and the function `getJsonPlaceholder` returns undefined, which is the default in JS for functions that do not return anything.

Here you can find a great [summary of async/await `.then()` and `.catch()` usecases in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019621/using-async-await-and-then-together).

And, finally, for your test case to pass, drop the `.then()`, assign the returned value of the `axios` request to a variable, and return this variable on the function `getWorkerId`, this should be enough!