# Using Axios in useEffect from an external file

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to export an axios call from an external file to my component, in useEffect. Im exporting the function and importing in the said component. The response is "undefined".

api_call.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')

export const getPublicCircles = async () => {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Language': 'fr',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    }
    await axios.get('https://myurl.com/api/this-info', { headers })
      .then(response => console.log(response)) 
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
  };
```

( I also tried with .then((response) => return response.data.data)

component.js

```
import * as  API from '../../api/api_call';

export default function PublicCircles() {

  const [circles, getCircles] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await API.getPublicCircles();
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(response)
      getCircles(response);
    }

    fetchData()
      .catch(console.error);;
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box>
      {circles === '' ? null :
      <PublicCircle circles={circles} />}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Here are the results (getting the info from the api_call.js file, not the PublicCirlces.js one.
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to receive a response in the useEffect 'response' you have to return the response from main the API call.

Comment: I'd like to point out that is a bad practice to use `await` together with then/catch chaining. This can create confusion about the return value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019621/using-async-await-and-then-together

Comment: You also don't return the contents of `axios.get` in your `getPublicCircles` function, you just await for it without storing anything anywhere.

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee Good catch! :) But be careful: the topic starter may use `return await` which isn't the same as returning the value after awaiting: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await

Comment: How should I do? I also did  .then((response) => return response.data.data) instead and it did not work either

Comment: @YohavRn instead of `await axios.get('https://myurl.com.....` use `const data = await axios.get('https://myurl.com......`, and in the next line add `return data`.

Comment: @Rusurano I get what you pointed out. Thanks , I completely overlooked that. My bad 

Comment: @Rusurano it worked thank you, wanna put it as an answer?

Comment: @YohavRn Sure! I'll compile an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is that the function `getPublicCircles` returns nothing, which is why any variable to which the result of this function call is assigned as a value, will be `undefined` per JavaScript rules, because a function that doesn't return any value will return `undefined`.

It's not a good idea to use `async/await` and `then/catch` in handling a promise together. Below is the example of handling it correctly with `try/catch` and `async/await`:

```
export const getPublicCircles = async () => {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Language': 'fr',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    }
    
    try {
        const data = await axios.get('https://myurl.com/api/this-info', { headers });

        return data;
    } catch(error) {
        console.error('error',error);
    }
}
```

Comment: And then how to use it in the useEffect hook?
In different component? I'm trying nad no positive results