# Why does this recursive function not run asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous, recursion

I have a `start(node, array)` function that should perform a DFS by traversing an object tree via recursive calls to an API through `callMsGraph(token, end)` until `image` properties are found at the end of the tree, at which point they are pushed to `array`. The function seems like it works, but I can't get the `output` unless I wrap it in a 2 second `setTimeout` which indicates the recursion is not being waited on to complete. I would want to play around with async/await more, but it's not at the top-level.

I'm not sure if the `nextNode.then` is doing anything or maybe `callMsGraph()` needs to be awaited on differently to how I know. A solution would be much appreciated.

```
shelfdb.data = async (accessToken) => {

    const token = accessToken;
    const endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/webgroup.sharepoint.com,23e7ef7a-a529-4dde-81ba-67afb4f44401,0fa8e0f7-1c76-4ad0-9b6e-a485f9bfd63c/drive/items/01GNYB5KPQ57RHLPZCJFE2QMVKT5U3NYY3/children'
    
    function start(node, array) {
        if(node.value.length > 0) {
            node.value.forEach(function(child) {
                var end = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/webgroup.sharepoint.com,23e7ef7a-a529-4dde-81ba-67afb4f44401,0fa8e0f7-1c76-4ad0-9b6e-a485f9bfd63c/drive/items/' + child.id + '/children';
                var nextNode = callMsGraph(token, end);
    
                nextNode.then(function(currResult) {
                    if (currResult.value.length > 0) {

                        if ('image' in currResult.value[0]) {
                            currResult.value.forEach(function(imgChild) {
                                let img = {
                                    'name': imgChild.name,
                                    'job': imgChild.parentReference.path.split("/")[6],
                                    'path': imgChild.webUrl,
                                    'id': imgChild.id
                                }
                                array.push(img);
                            })
                            // complete storing images at tail object, go one level up after loop
                            return;
                        }

                        // if no 'image' or value, go into child
                        start(currResult, array);
                    }
                }).catch(function(e) {
                    console.error(e.message);
                })
            })
        }
    
        return array;
    }
    
    
    var res = await callMsGraph(token, endpoint); // start recursion
    var output = start(res, []); 
    console.log(output); // only displays value if wrapped in setTimeout

    return output; // empty []

}
```

Each query to the API via `callMsGraph()`, returns an object like this, where subsequent queries are made with the `id` of each object/folder (as new endpoint) in `value` until an object with `image` property is found. The MS Graph API requires that folders are expanded at each level to access their children.

```
{
  id: '01GNYB5KPQ57RHLPZCJFE2QMVKT5U3NYY3'
  value: [
    {
      id: '01GNYB5KJMH5T4GXADUVFZRSITWZWNQROS',
      name: 'Folder1',
    },
    {
      id: '01GNYB5KMJKILOFDZ6PZBZYMXY4BGOI463',
      name: 'Folder2',
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the callMsGraph() helper:

```
function callMsGraph(accessToken, graphEndpoint) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    return fetch(graphEndpoint, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few places where you are not handling promises returned in you code. `nextNode.then` if your forEach loop is just "called", next line of the code will not wait for it to complete, forEach loop will complete execution before `then` callbacks are called.

I changed you code a bit, but I have no way to check if it works correctly due to i would need to populate dummy data for `callMsGraph` but if you encounter any - tell me and I'll modify the answer

```
shelfdb.data = async (accessToken) => {
  const token = accessToken;
  const endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/webgroup.sharepoint.com,23e7ef7a-a529-4dde-81ba-67afb4f44401,0fa8e0f7-1c76-4ad0-9b6e-a485f9bfd63c/drive/items/01GNYB5KPQ57RHLPZCJFE2QMVKT5U3NYY3/children'

  const images = [];

  async function start(node, array) {
    if (node.value.length <= 0) return array; // or === 0 or whatever

    for (const child of node.value) {
      const end = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/webgroup.sharepoint.com,23e7ef7a-a529-4dde-81ba-67afb4f44401,0fa8e0f7-1c76-4ad0-9b6e-a485f9bfd63c/drive/items/${child.id}/children`;
      const nextNode = await callMsGraph(token, end);
      if (nextNode.value.length > 0) {
        if ('image' in nextNode.value[0]) {
          const mapped = nextNode.value.map(imgChild => {
            return {
              'name': imgChild.name,
              'job': imgChild.parentReference.path.split("/")[6],
              'path': imgChild.webUrl,
              'id': imgChild.id
            }
          });
          array.push(...mapped);
        }

        // if no 'image' or value, go into child
        await start(nextNode, array);
      }
    }

    return array;
  }


  var res = await callMsGraph(token, endpoint);
  var output = await start(res, []);
  console.log(output);

  return output;
}
```

Also, please, feel free to add a try{} catch{} blocks in any place you need them, I skipped them

Comment: Works like a charm, definitely will avoid forEach() for asynchronous code in future.

Answer (score 3):

The rule with promises is that once you opt into one (more likely, are forced into it by a library), all code that needs to block for a result anywhere after it also has to await. You [can't "go back" to sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/) and if even a single piece of the promise chain between where the promise starts and where you want its result isn't awaited, the result will be unreachable<sup>*</sup>.

Taking a snippet of the code:

```
function start(node, array) { // not async!
    // ..
    node.value.forEach(function(child) { // doesn't await!
        // ..
        nextNode.then(function(currResult) {
        // this promise is not hooked up to anything!
        start(...) // recurse without await!
```

There's no `await` in front of `then`, `start` doesn't return a promise and isn't awaited recursively, and [`forEach` has no way to await its callback's asynchronous results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop), so each promise in the `nextNode.then` chain is orphaned into the void forever<sup>*</sup>.

The solution is a structure like this:

```
async function start(node, array) {
    // ..
    for (const child of node.value) {
        // ..
        const currResult = await callMsGraph(token, end);
        // ..
        await start(...);
        array.push(currResult);
    }
    // returns a promise implicitly
}

// ..
await start(...);
// `array` is populated here
```

Or `Promise.all`, which runs in parallel and returns an array (which could replace the parameter `array`):

```
function start(node, array) {
    return Promise.all(node.value.map(async child => {
        const currResult = await callMsGraph(token, end);
        // ..
        await start(...);
        return currResult;
    }));
}
```

I'd be happy to provide a minimal, runnable example, but the code you've provided isn't runnable, so you'll have to massage this a bit to work for you. If you make sure to `await` everything, you're good to go (and generally avoid mixing `.then` and `async`/`await`--the latter seems easier for this use case).

<sup>** (for all practical intents and purposes)*</sup>