# Firebase Callable Function can't return after callback

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm new in JS world and callbacks.
Why I can't return response after then function for the Firebase callable functions?
It returns empty if I return like shown below. I guess it doesn't wait for the response, response has data.output variable actually.

```
exports.testApi = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("height", "512");

const response = await axios.post('https://....', formData, {

  headers: formData.getHeaders()
})
.then((response) => {
            
        console.log(response.data);
        return {'imageURL':response.data.output};
          })
          .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                  });


}
);
```

It works with this format

```
const response = await axios.post('https://..', formData, {
  
  headers: formData.getHeaders()
})

return {'imageURL':response.data.output};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main attraction of `async` and `await` is cleaner syntax, in particular syntax that doesn't use `then` (opinion). You can mix them but I would always try to avoid it, especially here where the task is so simple.

```
exports.testApi = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("height", "512");
        
        // Wait for post to give us a response.
        const response = await axios.post('https://....', formData, {
            headers: formData.getHeaders()
        });

        // If we get here, we waited and got a response. Proceed.
        console.log(response.data);
        return {'imageURL': response.data.output}; 
    } catch (error) {
        // If we get here, post threw an error (assuming it throws).
        // And we never executed any lines after const response = await...
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Side note: Firebase Cloud Functions have to be properly terminated and this function does not. For example, if `post` throws an error and control flows to the catch block then the function will simply timeout because we haven't returned a `Promise` or thrown a compliant error.

Comment: Thank you for response and suggestion. I'll convert it into this format. Do you know why I can't return in then callback?

Comment: @OzgurSahin read the following to better understand how to use `then` with `await`, it can become syntactically complex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019621/using-async-await-and-then-together