# Playwright page.goto: Navigation failed because page was closed on Render

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm using playwright in my Render server. Locally, I don't have any error. But on the Render server, sometimes it works with the goto function but sometimes I get an error. I have a link list(I added example links in the source code) and give the functions. I couldn't find any solution for this. This is the error log:

```
    : GOTO: page.goto: Navigation failed because page was closed!
May 16 06:28:40 PM =========================== logs ===========================
May 16 06:28:40 PM navigating to "https://in.investing.com/equities/housing-development-finance-technical?timeFrame=60", waiting until "load"
May 16 06:28:40 PM ============================================================
May 16 06:28:40 PM at getResults (/usr/src/app/index.js:151:10)
May 16 06:28:40 PM at async scrape (/usr/src/app/index.js:223:23) {
May 16 06:28:40 PM name: 'Error'
May 16 06:28:40 PM }
May 16 06:28:40 PM ERROR => page.$eval: Target page, context or browser has been closed
May 16 06:28:40 PM at getResults (/usr/src/app/index.js:160:33)
May 16 06:28:40 PM at async scrape (/usr/src/app/index.js:223:23) {
May 16 06:28:40 PM name: 'Error'
May 16 06:28:40 PM }
May 16 06:28:40 PM ERROR => browserContext.newPage: Target page, context or browser has been closed
May 16 06:28:40 PM at getResults (/usr/src/app/index.js:133:34)
May 16 06:28:40 PM at async scrape (/usr/src/app/index.js:223:23) {
May 16 06:28:40 PM name: 'Error'
May 16 06:28:40 PM }
```

Code:

```
Link_Lst = [
  "https://in.investing.com/equities/axis-bank-technical",
  "https://in.investing.com/equities/tata-motors-ltd-technical",
  "https://in.investing.com/equities/icici-bank-ltd-technical",
..}
   async function getResults(lnk) {
      const results = [];
      const timeFrames = [1, 5, 15];
    
    
      for (const i of timeFrames) {
        try {
    
        const browser = await chromium.launch({
          args: [
                  '--no-sandbox',
                  '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                  '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                  '--single-process',
                  "--no-zygote",
                  '--ignore-certificate-errors',
                  "--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess"
                  // "--remote-debugging-port"
                ],   
               defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
          executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
          headless: chromium.headless,
        });
        const context = await browser.newContext({
          userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
        });
        
          const page = await context.newPage();
    
          const url = `${lnk}?timeFrame=${i * 60}`;
          console.log(`Getting: ${url}`);
    
          await page.evaluate(() => navigator.userAgent)
    
          await page.setViewportSize({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
    
           await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
          await page
            .goto(url, { waitUntil: "load", timeout: 0 })
            .then(() => console.log("Goto Success!!"))
            .catch((err) => console.log("GOTO:", err));
    
    
          await page
            .waitForSelector("section.forecast-box-graph", {
              visible: true,
            })
            .then(() => console.log("Success"))
            .catch(async (err) => console.log("ERR", err));
    
          const status = await page.$eval(
            "section.forecast-box-graph .title",
            (el) => el.textContent
          );
          const bank_name = await page.$eval("h1.main-title.js-main-title", (el) =>
            el.textContent.trim()
          );
    
          results.push({
            bankName: bank_name,
            status: status,
            lnk: lnk.replace(/-/g, " ").split("/").pop(),
            url: url,
          });
    
         // await page.close();
          await browser.close();
        } catch (e) {
    
          console.log("ERROR =>", e);
        }
      }
      sendRequest();
      return results;
    }
```

....

```
  async function scrape() {
  while (true) {
    for (const lnk of Link_Lst) {
    let Buy_ = true;
    let Sell_ = true;
    let focusCount = 0
    


      const results = await getResults(lnk);
}}
```

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] without the links, but there are some questionable practices here. `await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);` can hang your script forever. If you want a long timeout, fine, but if it doesn't resolve in 10 minutes, you'll want to log and restart that rather than block forever. Secondly, [don't mix `await` and `then`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75785234/6243352) because it can lead to confusion and errors. Thirdly, I'd use a `finally` block to call `browser.close()`. Fourthly, `await page.evaluate(() => navigator.userAgent)` does nothing as far as I can tell.

Comment: I add links in source code. I try your suggetions but same error I have.

Comment: Thanks. What's `sendRequest()`? Would that need to be `await`ed?

Comment: this function include (sendREquest() ) send get request to "/" (root) path. This is not related witht his issue because when I remove it I get same error.