# React native and correct results retrieval

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code:

```
const getUser = async () => {
    await firestore()
     .collection('users')
     .doc(user.uid)
     .get()
     .then(( doc ) => {
       if( doc.exists ) {
         setUserData(doc.data());
         setLoading(false);
       }
     })
   };
```

Question: is this code correct?
I mean combining async/await with then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using async await and .then together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019621/using-async-await-and-then-together)