# Puppeteer - "Requesting main frame too early!"

Tags: javascript, error-handling, puppeteer, browser-automation

I've created a function using Puppeteer that checks if the user is logged in. Basically at first it checks if browser, page are open and then looks for selector and depending if item was found returns true/false.

```js
export async function checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() {
  const logger = getLogger('checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()');
  try {
    if (!page || !browser) {
      logger.info('page or browser is not open');
      return false;
    }

    logger.info('page or browser is open');
    await delay(randomWaitTimeSeconds1_2());

    // await page.waitForSelector(selector);
    const btn = await page.$(selector);

    logger.info(`user is logged in - ${!!btn ? 'YES' : 'NO'}`);
    return !!btn;
  } catch (e) {
    logError('checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()', e);
  }
}
```

Sometimes error "Error: Requesting main frame too early!" happens when I'm trying to select required element or when I'm waiting for selector (one line above, the commented one).
Full error message:

```js
[2023-10-02T01:58:06.825] [ERROR] checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() - Error: Requesting main frame too early!
    at assert (C:\Users\simon\Desktop\tb-project-pup\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\util\assert.js:28:15)
    at FrameManager.mainFrame (C:\Users\simon\Desktop\tb-project-pup\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\FrameManager.js:219:32)
    at CdpPage.mainFrame (C:\Users\simon\Desktop\tb-project-pup\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\Page.js:407:35)
    at CdpPage.$ (C:\Users\simon\Desktop\tb-project-pup\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\Page.js:324:31)
    at checkIfUserIsLoggedIn (file:///C:/Users/simon/Desktop/tb-project-pup/main/checkIfUserIsLoggedIn.js:19:38)
```

The page in which this happens has some sort of timer. And when timer goes to 00 then page is reloaded automatically ("?reload=auto") which I think causes the error. But that happens very rarely.

I'm trying to understand is why this error causes Puppeteer to shut down and close the browser? In other functions I sometimes get error `TimeoutError: Waiting for selector` .el `failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded`, or another error `ProtocolError: Protocol error (DOM.describeNode): Cannot find context with specified id` but in those scenarios error doesn't close the browser but this one does.

Maybe someone can help me understand why puppeteer is being closed? And also help me find a correct solution for this?

I think maybe before `const btn = await page.$(selector);` I could add something like
`await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', });` but that navigation does not happen very often, it can take up to 2+minutes for page to reload.
Also I was thinking maybe I could introduce another try catch block to re-run this function if error happens, e.g.:
(but if I do this, do I still need my original try/catch block?)

```js
const anchorElement = await page.$(selector).catch(async () => {
      retryCount++;
      if (retryCount < 3) {
        await checkIfUserIsLoggedIn();
       // OR await page.$(selector)
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That said, [don't mix async and `then`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75785234/6243352)

Answer (score 3):

This might be helpful, just ran into this as well with async code.

You might have a race condition with regards to where you close the browser, so check that out as well and ensure your async code runs before the browser instance is closed.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using puppeteer for four year, in the same project. this issue appear randomly more or less after this release of the new headless mode https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/ . Generally I obtained several time the "Requesting main frame too early!" issue immediatly after that release of puppeteer. I tried to open a bug report, but i have no idea about how to replicate the problem, because it is random.

I can obtain this error in different method

1. page.goTo
2. page.waitForSelector

the point of the sourcecode that raise that exception is this one.

[image]

Comment: downgrading to puppeteer 20.5.0 works. i opened https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/11246

Comment: I had a simmilar Error with Puppeteer Version 21.4.1 but that is fixed for me with Version 21.5.0 now

Answer (score 0):

page.$ won't wait for it, you want page.waitForSelector:

```
let loggedIn = await page.waitForSelector('[href*=logout]', { timeout: 10000 }).catch(e => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue with Highcharts Export Server v3.0, which uses puppeteer. After reading the comment by @fwebdev I upgraded the puppeteer version required by node-export-server to 21.5.1 and that solved the problem.

Comment: This issue still persists in version 21.5.2 and it cannot be reproduced reliably.
It happens during the call to Page.goto() at random times, especially after the application has been running for a while (4-5 hours seems to be the sweet spot).
The main problem is that once this happens, all future calls to Page.goto() will immediately fail with the same error and there's no apparent way to work around this without restarting the application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I fixed it by not using the `page.waitForTimeout()` method; see [puppeteer: wait N seconds before continuing to the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919013/puppeteer-wait-n-seconds-before-continuing-to-the-next-line/73676564#73676564)

I just replaced it with `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))`.

Are you using the `page.waitForTimeout()` anywhere in your code, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution.

If you look in the puppeteer docs, it says a puppeteer instance is set to timeout in 30000ms (30seconds) by default.

[puppeteer docs launchoptions](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.launchoptions)

so when initialising the instance set the timeout option higher. I set mine to 31536000000ms (365 days)

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({timeout: 31536000000});
```