# Failure to catch dynamic elem (image) with Puppeteer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, puppeteer

I load page, wait till the image is loaded (at `page.goto()`) and selector is found yet *I fail to catch already loaded img*, always receiving `Promise { <pending> }`...
**How to get image URL ?**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var $url = "https://twitter.com/astro_greek/status/1754801971725312352";

const $selector_timeout =  5000; // default "selector wait" timeout 
const img_selector = 'img'; // [alt="Image"]

(async () => {
    // Launch the browser and open a new blank page
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto($url , { waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}); // all dynamic items are loaded        
     
    let image2 = await page.waitForSelector(img_selector, {timeout: $selector_timeout} )
      .then(() => {     
        console.log("Success with selector.");
        let image = page.$(img_selector)
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("Image is caught." );
            page.$eval( img_selector, el => el.scrollIntoView());
            let body = page.$(img_selector )
            .then((el)=>{  
                console.log("typeof el: " + typeof el);
                console.log("Element outerHtml: " + el.getProperty('outerHTML'));
                console.log("Element innerHtml: " + el.getProperty('innerHTML'));
                console.log("Element href: " + el.getProperty('href')); 
            });
            console.log("Body: " );
            console.log(body);    
        }).catch((err)=>{ console.log(err);});
        console.log("Image: ");
        console.log(image);
    }).catch((err)=> { 
        console.log("Failure to get tax info HTML element. ERR:", err);                                
    } );
    console.log("Image 2: " + image2);      
 
    await browser.close();
})();
```

The result for all 3 cases: *image*, *body* and *el* are `Promise { <pending> }` or `[object Promise]`:

```
Success with selector.
Image:
Promise { <pending> }
Image 2: undefined
Image is caught.
Body:
Promise { <pending> }
Element: JSHandle@node
Promise { <pending> }
typeof el: object
Element outerHtml: [object Promise]
Element innerHtml: [object Promise]
Element href: [object Promise]
```

### Update 1

When I try the following after page.goto():

```
 let img = await page.$("img")
    .then((response)=> {  
        //console.dir(response); 
        console.log("Image properties: "  + response.getProperties()); 
        //let href = response.getProperty('href').jsonValue();
        //console.log("Image href: "  + href); 
    });
```

the result is:

```
Image properties: [object Promise]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski, it does not. See **Update 1**.

Comment: This nested code combining `then` and `await` is an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75785234/6243352). Mixing the two leads to unreadable, buggy code. `page.$eval( img_selector, el => el.scrollIntoView());` was never awaited, and both of your `page.$(img_selector )` calls are disconnected from the main promise chain, creating race conditions. The code will close the browser in parallel with these selections, because all happen simultaneously after the `waitForSelector` call. If you remove all `then`s and strictly use `await` in front of every Puppeteer call, you should be OK.

Comment: As far as getting the actual src property of the image: `page.$eval("img", el => el.src)` or `page.$eval("img", el => el.getAttribute("src"))`, but that's sort of beside the point here--the first order of business is writing correct code to isolate the element before bothering to pull anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries and errors:

```
/*
let img_all_properties = await img.getProperties();
console.log("img all props type: " + (typeof img_all_properties)  );
for (const [key, value] of img_all_properties) {  
    console.log(`The value for key ${key} is ${value}`);
}
*/
let img_src_prop = await img.getProperty('src');
let img_src = await img_src_prop.jsonValue();
console.log("img src: " + img_src );
```

with result:

```
img src: https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1470781968971358211/2Qd3T5VJ_normal.jpg
```