Vue Js Frontend not displaying Data of Laravel API
Working with Laravel backend 10 and VueJs 3 api. My Browser Inspect displaying backend data array employees, but on my VueJs it is not displaying data.
EmployeeList.vue
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Birth Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Gender</th>
                    <th scope="col">Hire Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody v-for="employee in employees" :key="employee.emp_no">
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.emp_no }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.first_name }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.last_name }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.birth_date }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.gender }}</th>
                    <th scope="row">{{ employee.hire_date }}</th>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        name:'EmployeeList',
        data() {
            return {
                employees:Array
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getEmployees();
        },
        methods:{
            async getEmployees() {
                let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees';
                await axios.get(url).then(response => {
                    this.employees = response.data.employees;
                    console.log(this.employees);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Employee List Component Mounted');
        }
    }
</script>

Vue js DevTools displaying following
PROPS
name:"default"
route:undefined

PROVIDED
Symbol([vue-router]: router view depth):1
Symbol([vue-router]: router view location matched):Object (Computed)
Symbol([vue-router]: router view location):Object (Computed)
fullPath:"/"
path:"/"
query:Object (empty)
hash:""
name:"EmployeeList"
params:Object (empty)
matched:Array[1]
meta:Object (empty)
redirectedFrom:undefined
href:"/"

Edit Dev Tools Object
0   Object { emp_no: 1, birth_date: "2014-09-10", first_name: "Kottu", … }
emp_no  1
birth_date  "2014-09-10"
first_name  "kottu"
last_name   "mataoni"
gender  "male"
hire_date   "2024-06-06"
created_at  "2024-06-06 15:10:28"
updated_at  null
titles  [ {…}, {…} ]
salaries    [ {…} ]

Unable to guess what is the problem? Can someone help me this?

Why you have defined data as employees:Array, you can update it to employees: []. Also do you have any other error in the console?

Also try avoiding async/await and then togther. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019621/using-async-await-and-then-together

Can share the object that you're receiving in your devtools, network tab?

@YashMaheshwari no other errors

@kissu please see my edited question I have added devtools objects. I have other Salary and Title Models with Relationship Employee

@Matakoththuwakoni You have also missed adding table tag and wrap thead and tbody in it.
